# Set dropdown item as SELECTED, if calling from product parent page

Tags: php, html

1. I have one single inquiry form (php page) that contain a drop-down SELECT containing all products.

```php
<select class="form-control" name="model_name" required="" id="modals">
 <option> Choose Model *</option>
  <?php
$fetch = $, com_in->prepare("SELECT * FROM main_product_tbl WHERE type='1'");
$fetch->execute();
$c = 1;
foreach ($fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $key)
{
   echo '
       <option value="' . $key['product_id'] . '">' . $key['model_name'] . '</option> ';
    $c++;
}
?>
</select>
```

2. All these products have their separate/individual web pages.

Each product page has Inquiry Button, that loads the Inquiry Form (a php page)
there user has to select particular product from the drop-down SELECT.

I want that if user press the inquiry button (from any product page), it should load the Inquiry page and **the respective product item should be automatically selected in the drop-down.**

Kindly help.

Comment: you would have to pass your product id to enquiry form. in your form page, in option tag check if product id matches the id in your dropdown and set it as selected

Comment: Please post some code... You just pass the productId as a get parameter and then extract it on Inquiry page in php or javascript to change the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Pass product id or name through url and fetch value from db on inquiry page
[www.site.com/enquiry.php?=productid](http://www.site.com/enquiry.php?=productid)
On enquiry page

fetch details from database useing id or product name

Answer (score 0):

As first you must set a variable/cookie with the current product. In this example, it will be

```php
$product
```

Then, add this code inside the `<option>` tag

```php
// We check if the product name is equal to the selected product and then select it
if($product == $key['model_name']){echo "selected";}
```